# Difference between "highcharts-angular" and "angular-highcharts" node modules (for Angular v7)

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular7

My application will be Angular v7 and Highcharts (latest version)

I'm wondering what's the difference between the below 2 node modules, each is listed on the [HighCharts tutorial page](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/posts/tutorials/), and they look the same:

- Node module: [highcharts-angular](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-angular-wrapper/)
- Node module: [angular7-highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/highcharts-and-angular-7/)

I've a simple example working with "highcharts-angular" but unsure which I should be using.

Any thoughts/guidance would be great.
Thanks Ro

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the posted articles `highcharts-angular` is Highcharts Angular Official Wrapper and `angular7-highcharts` is just a sample folder for the Angular project just only in this tutorial.