# What is the difference between angular-highcharts and highcharts-angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

My team is currently using both [angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) and [highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) across different projects. From what I understand, one seem to be a directive and other a wrapper. Can someone please help me understand the difference between the two and advise which one I should use for my projects going forward?

Comment: Maybe related?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023723/difference-between-highcharts-angular-and-angular-highcharts-node-modules-f

Comment: @GeekyI I have looked into the that thread. It talks about comparing highcharts-angular with a different library which was created only for tutorial purposes.

Answer (score 2):

`highcharts-angular` is the only official wrapper for angular created and supported by the Highsoft. `angular-highcharts` is a 3rd party product, that might be helpful but it is not officially supported. For safety and support reasons, I would recommend using the `highcharts-angular`.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Answer (score 1):

We should use `highcharts-angular` as its the official wrapper of highcharts. Looks like `angular-highcharts` and `angular2-highcharts` both not working after upgrading to angular 11

Comment: Tested locally and on stackblitz. Everything works as expected with `Angular 11`. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line What do you mean by saying `both not working after upgrading to angular 11`?

Comment: no `angular2-highcharts` is not working in angular 11

Comment: Right now I'm talking only about the `highcharts-angular` which works well in that case.

Comment: any way I found my answer angular2-highcharts works with Angular8 because that version uses the "View Engine" compiler while Angular11 uses the Ivy compiler. angular2-highcharts does not support the new "Ivy compiler". `highcharts-angular` will work perfectly fine